# Setting up perfmon across various servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance, perfmon

I set up some performance gathering in Performance Monitor (perfmon) on a particular server. (I setup a Data Collector Set for the server, with specific Data Collectors, setup start and stop condition, etc.) I'd like to setup identical performance gathering on the rest of the servers. (There's about 12.)

I'd like to keep all of the performance monitoring on one server. My first set of questions are about running the actual numbers. Should I run the data collectors and centralize them to one server, setting the appropriate values in perfmon all under the "Monitor" server? Or, should I run all of the performance gathering in their respective servers, and have a nightly batch script propagate the output files to the monitor server?

My second set of questions are about convenience. I'd like to simply copy all of the settings for a collector set (which represents a server), and have the identical collectors start for another server. Does anyone know a way to do this quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the perfmon process on a per server basis will have more impact on the measured server than running the perfmon process on a separate server.

If I recall correctly under 2008 I believe you can export the set as a file and edit the XML to copy sets. I'd have to set up a 2k8 server and verify (this is much improved in 2012)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, Jim. Can you elaborate on the first point, please? What does it mean if the perfmon process has more of an impact on the measured server?

Comment: actually running perfmon will impact the cputime/memory etc of the server you are running permon on.  The only real impact on the target server for remote measurement is on the network interface.